# Linux - I ve chmoded all my server

Tags: linux, centos, chmod

I have made a big mistake in a wrong command and ended up chmoding 777 all my server.

Result is no service want to start because of writable files.

Is there a way to fix this like a default restore without loosing my database/files?

PS: I m on centos 64 bit

PS2 I can t access ssh on my server but I still have webmin access so I can execute command from it

Comment: reinstalling is probably the easiest solution. I wouldn't trust that server.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath if I resintall i will loose all my content right? I have no backup of my db nor my files

Comment: You could start sshd, shutdown the web service, backup the server, then reinstall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling is probably the only way to be sure... but google shows

> google: rpm set file permissions

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/reset-rhel-centos-fedora-package-file-permission.html
RPM syntax to fix permission
To set permissions of files in a package, enter:
rpm --setperms {packagename}
Reset the permissions of the all installed RPM packages
and
You need to use combination of rpm and a shell for loop command as follows:

```
for p in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setperms $p; done
```

That should fix a lot. ... but only files from a package.  Other data... search for files with mode 777 and figure out what you need.  For most maybe chmod o-w FILE would work.  It's risky, it doesn't restore the permissions, but only changes them.

```
find / -perm -777 -exec chmod o-w {} \; # There are faster ways using xargs
```

Comment: I have found it on google later too. Thank you very much that was the solution. When i was able to access ssh, I then used sftp to save my data, and then reinstalled the VPS.